# List comprehension with binary outcome and time data in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to write an if statement so that it labels "1" when a certain condition is fulfilled and "0" if not. This is my code for now but I can't get it to work..

```
order = [1 for x in df.orderdate if x >= 2019-02-27  and x <= 2019-03-31 else 0]
```

(I'm also trying to use list comprehension here as well.) For the "orderdate" column I've converted everything to datetime64[ns]. Now I want to know if the customer placed an order between 2019-02-27 and 2019-03-31 or not. I want to create a new column with only 1s and 0s in it and append the column to a df I created.

Thank you so much for the help!!!!

Comment: `order = [1 if x >= "2019-02-27"  and x <= "2019-03-31" else 0 for x in df.orderdate]`

Comment: terminology note: `if` is not a looping structure, it is a branching structure

Comment: Your expression will evaluate as "if x >= 2019 (minus) 02 (minus) 27 and x <= 2019 (minus) 03 (minus) 31"...

Comment: Yes sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

you should do this the pandas way since you already have a dataframe it looks like.
**you should not loop**, as that really defeats the purpose of pandas

```
# this assumes df.orderdate is a pandas.DateTime column
binaryList = df.orderdate.between("2019-02-27","2019-03-31").astype(int)
```

to break this down further

```
 df.orderdate.between("2019-02-27","2019-03-31")
```

will return a series of `[True,False,True,True,etc]` , normally you might use this as a row selector for the df(eg `orders_between_feb27_and_mar31 = df[df.orderdate.between("2019-02-27","2019-03-31")]`)

we can then cast `astype(int)` which will convert True to 1 and False to 0

if you then wanted to convert it into a single integer (eg bitmask)

```
bitmask_bin = "".join(df.orderdate.between("2019-02-27","2019-03-31").astype(int).astype(str))
bitmask_int = int(bitmask_bin,2)
```

Comment: Hi Joran This is so helpful

Comment: `data = {"binaryList": df.orderdate.between("2019-02-27","2019-03-31").astype(int) }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)`   I now try to put it in a dataframe but somehow it always says 'Series' object is not callable. Did I do wrong anywhere? Thank you so much!!

Comment: just do my example code above and then `df['binaryList'] = binaryList`

Answer (score 0):

When you have list comprehension and you want `if` and `else`, then the general structure is as follows:

`[if_is_true if condition else else_is_true for x in sequence]`

Hence,

```
order = [1 if x >= "2019-02-27"  and x <= "2019-03-31" else 0 for x in df.orderdate]
```

One more thing, you are comparing with int, you have to convert to string